# PHP looping on cURL API call

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I'm a newbie coder, and this is my first time working with PHP and cURL. I am making an API call for which I have already set up a cURL request that gets me back a JSON object.

What I am trying to do now is set the cURL call to loop through an $payers array that contains multiple $payer_id's for which I would like to make make and individual request at a time, print out a PRETTY_PRINT JSON object and the make the next request for the next $payer_id from the $payers array.

This is the code I have set up, obviously for security purposes info and api url are fake, but this is the structure I'm using right now. Like I mentioned before, if you remove the foreach part of the code and manually enter the $payer_id number to the code I have, it works and returns the JSON object I want... But I want to be able to set up code to use the array of $payers and print out the JSON object for me.

Any help, guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php

  /* API url*/
  $url = 'https://testapi.com/cov/all.json';

  $payers = array("00002", "00112");

  /* Assign parameter values here */

  foreach ($payers as $payer) {
  $api_key = '1111122222233333';
  $payer_id = echo "$payer"; 
  $provider_first_name = 'laura';
  $provider_last_name = 'brown';
  $provider_npi = '444445555';
  $member_first_name = 'billy';
  $member_last_name = 'bob';
  $dependent_ssn = '111-22-3333';
  $member_dob  = '1988-11-11';

  /* $_GET Parameters to Send */
  $params = array( 

    'api_key'           =>   $api_key,
    'payer_id'          =>   $payer_id,
    'provider_first_name'  =>   $provider_first_name,
    'provider_last_name'   =>   $provider_last_name,
    'provider_npi'       =>   $provider_npi,
    'member_first_name'          =>   $member_first_name,
    'member_last_name'           =>   $member_last_name,
    'dependent_ssn'                 =>   $dependent_ssn,
    'member_dob'                 =>   $member_dob
  ); 

  /* Update URL to container Query String of Paramaters */
  $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
  /* cURL Resource */
  $ch = curl_init();
  /* Set URL */
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  /* Tell cURL to return the output */
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  /* Execute cURL, Return Data */
  $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $decoded = json_decode($curl_response, true);

  echo '<pre>';
    echo json_encode($decoded, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  echo '</pre>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: you have an error here `$payer_id = echo "$payer"; `

Comment: There's no need to do `echo "$payer"`. `$payer` will suffice. 
Also, instead of assigning same name key/value pairs you could use `compact('api_key', 'payer_id', ...)`.
You should make sure you setup the right context for the API request (be it POST, GET, PUT[, DELETE, ..]).

Comment: Thank you guys ... @RamRaider I did what you suggested on your post below,  and now it does access the array, but it is only returning the first JSON for the first $payer_id. Is there anything else that would make it loop through to the next payer_id in the array? or do you think it is limited due to it being a large JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comment above there was a minor error in the declaration of the variable `$payer` - the echo was problematic.

Also, I think you should be able to use the curl handle repeatedly for the various payers in the array - declare outside the loop and assign the new url with parameters on each iteration.

[ [download cacert.pem from curl.haxx.se](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) ]

```
<?php

    /* API url*/
    $baseurl = 'https://testapi.com/cov/all.json';

    $payers = array("00002", "00112");
    $data=array();


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    /* when ever I have to use curl to an ssl host I always include these options */
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla-whatever-ua-string' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath('c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem') ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );


    /* Assign parameter values here */
    foreach( $payers as $payer ) {
        $api_key = '1111122222233333';
        $payer_id = $payer; 
        $provider_first_name = 'laura';
        $provider_last_name = 'brown';
        $provider_npi = '444445555';
        $member_first_name = 'billy';
        $member_last_name = 'bob';
        $dependent_ssn = '111-22-3333';
        $member_dob  = '1988-11-11';

        /* $_GET Parameters to Send */
        $params = array( 
            'api_key'               =>   $api_key,
            'payer_id'              =>   $payer_id,
            'provider_first_name'   =>   $provider_first_name,
            'provider_last_name'    =>   $provider_last_name,
            'provider_npi'          =>   $provider_npi,
            'member_first_name'     =>   $member_first_name,
            'member_last_name'      =>   $member_last_name,
            'dependent_ssn'         =>   $dependent_ssn,
            'member_dob'            =>   $member_dob
        ); 

        /* Update URL to container Query String of Paramaters */
        $url = $baseurl . '?' . http_build_query($params);

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        $curl_response = curl_exec( $ch );

        $decoded = json_decode($curl_response, true);

        /* store all responses for later consumption */
        $data[]=$curl_response;
        /* for debug, show responses */
        echo '<pre>',json_encode( $decoded, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ),'</pre>';
    }

  curl_close($ch);

  if( !empty( $data ) ) print_r( $data );


?>

/* output from print_r($data) */
Array
(
    [0] => {"0":{"api_key":"1111122222233333","payer_id":"00002","provider_first_name":"laura","provider_last_name":"brown","provider_npi":"444445555","member_first_name":"billy","member_last_name":"bob","dependent_ssn":"111-22-3333","member_dob":"1988-11-11","section":"curlapi"},"errors":[],"info":[]}
    [1] => {"0":{"api_key":"1111122222233333","payer_id":"00112","provider_first_name":"laura","provider_last_name":"brown","provider_npi":"444445555","member_first_name":"billy","member_last_name":"bob","dependent_ssn":"111-22-3333","member_dob":"1988-11-11","section":"curlapi"},"errors":[],"info":[]}
)
```

Comment: Thank you @RamRaider I did what you suggested on your post below, and now it does access the array, but it is only returning the first JSON for the first $payer_id. Is there anything else that would make it loop through to the next payer_id in the array? or do you think it is limited due to it being a large JSON object? ......Actually I just checked the API and it is processing both calls, but only the first one is being printed out. How do  you think this can be made to print out both JSON objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://testapi.com/cov/all.json';
```

Followed by

```
$url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
```

in the foreach loop, appends the new parameters to string everytime, I would do this:

```
$base_url = 'https://testapi.com/cov/all.json';
```

Followed by

```
$url =  $base_url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
```

Comment: Thanks @Raz0rwire I did what you suggested on your post below,  and now it does access the array, but it is only returning the first JSON for the first $payer_id. Is there anything else that would make it loop through to the next payer_id in the array? or do you think it is limited due to it being a large JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$payer_id = echo "$payer"; 
           ^^^
```

`echo` is a language construct. it is not a function, and has no return value. it simply performs output. So effectively that code is running as

```
$payer_id = null;
```

Try

```
$payer_id = $payer;
```

instead. Note the lack of `"`. They're totally unecessary if you're just trying to copy the value from one variable to another with no changes.

Comment: So this question is off-topic : typo?